# Can 'mongoid-minitest' gem be used for writing controller test cases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, minitest, mongoid3

I am using 'mongoid-minitest' for writing test suite for my app
I have successfully added test cases for models using this gem. 
I tried adding controller test cases.

users_controller_test.rb

```
  require 'test_helper'
  describe UsersController do
    describe '#index' do
      it 'render index view' do
        get :index 
      end
    end
  end
```

But running command `ruby -I test test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb` is throwing error:
`undefined method 'get' for #<#<Class:0x00000006592e68>:0x00000007a7d9b8>` when `get :index` is executed.